# Adding a method to the Array class via a proc/block?

Tags: ruby, arrays, block, proc

I'm trying to add extra functionality in the Array class to take in a block. I think I've mostly got that down, however, I'm not sure of the syntax I want to use when calling the method uses a .to_proc / & casting for predefined methods (eg. `.odd?` ).

I have the following code:

```
class Array 

  def keep
    each do |user_array_element|
      user_array_element
      if yield(user_array_element) == true 
        kept_elements ||= []
        kept_elements << user_array_element
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Trying to get the following test to pass:

```
assert_equal [1, 3], [1, 2, 3].keep(&:odd?)
```

Comment: You may wish to have `keep` return an enumerator if no block is given, so it can be chained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test isn't passing because `each` returns the enumerable that it is called upon. To fix, change your definition like so:

```
class Array 
  def keep
    [].tap do |kept_elements|
      self.each do |element|
        kept_elements << element if (yield(element) == true)
      end
    end # will return kept_elements
  end
end
```

An alternative is using `each_with_object`:

```
class Array 
  def keep
    self.each_with_object([]) do |element, kept_elements|           
      kept_elements << element if (yield(element) == true)
    end # will return kept_elements
  end
end
```

The code above is just to show you how to get your own code to work. But essentially, you're writing a method for what `select` already does (except that it selects any element for which the block doesn't yield `nil` or `false`).

Answer (score 2):

Your `keep` method needs to return the array that has the kept elements. I modified your code a little, this should work:

```
class Array 
  def keep
    kept_elements = []
    each do |user_array_element|
      if yield(user_array_element) == true 
        kept_elements << user_array_element
      end
    end
    kept_elements
  end
end
```